# Setting up client-specific overrides for SCSS project

Tags: sass

I'm integrating SCSS into an existing product with a few dozen clients. I'm fairly new to the technology, and was wondering if there's a standardized way to accomplish what I'm trying to do.

I'd like to set up the project in such a way that I can have client-specific overrides to the default. Be able to do something like this:

```
- scss_dir
    - default_dir
         - main.scss
         - _stuff.scss
         - _more_stuff.scss
    - client_1_dir
    - client_2_dir
         - _stuff.scss
```

When I compile the SCSS files, the resulting CSS files will be based mostly on the default settings but with the possibility for client-specific overrides.

Is there a standardized way to do this?

One idea that came to mind would be to copy all the files to a temp directory and have the client-specific files simply overwrite the defaults. I'm not thrilled about that since it would mean copying an entire file if you wanted to change a single thing, and the files would almost certainly fall out of sync as new features are added.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with `@import` statements if you put all the default CSS in a partial and each client specific CSS in it's own partial. Something like this:

**client-one.scss**

```
@import '_default-styles.scss';
@import '_client-one.scss';
```

**client-two.scss**

```
@import '_default-styles.scss';
@import '_client-two.scss';
```